# Cakephp ACL ARO_ACO

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, acl

I've been working on a CRM for about 5 months and we are about to launch it, I am having an exhausting problem with Cake's ACL. I understand the concepts to a degree. The problem I'm having is with CRUD permissions in the ARO_ACO join table. As I understand it, I create permissions on a given controller/action. That alright, but I don't understand why denying just even one node out of the CRUD portion of the ARO_ACO table, completely denies the user access. I have more than 200 controller actions, this would seem like a complete waste of time, if I were to set up permissions across the board and have to deny access that deeply.

Since every action has a record, why would a "delete" action have CRUD on that action?

Example:

```
1;17;1;"1";"1";"1";"1"       << full access to admin group on all controllers.
15;19;14;"-1";"-1";"-1";"-1" << deny delete action on just one controller
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is how Cake is. I had a similar issue and ended up fixing my ACL problem using the Alaxos ACL plugin. At first, it was a little troublesome, but after a few attempts I got it to work.

[Check it out here...](http://www.alaxos.ch/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl)

Comment: Thank you, I was messing around with it for a while there and came to that conclusion myself. Funny. Thanks a lot this is way easier to manage.

Comment: No problem. Going forward any application I have to develop I will make sure I bake my app, install ACL and make the other necessary changes after. I will never save ACL for the end of my app again.